# Wheatstone bridge with zero offset voltage

Tags: common-mode, wheatstone-bridge

Can I power a Wheatstone bridge circuit with a positive voltage (say +5) on one side and negative (-5) on the other, such that the output common mode voltage is at 0V?  I don't see any reason why not, but I haven't seen before. Are there any foreseeable problems with doing this?

Comment: This will only occur with a balanced bridge.

Comment: Terminology technicality - "offset voltage" typically would refer to the differential output of the bridge with no input applied - it's the static error component of the measurement. What you're looking at would normally be referred to at the "common-mode voltage" (as tobalt mentions in the answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are no problems with it. You can power it with whatever you want/have, to set the common mode voltage accordingly.